# sed- insert text before and after pattern

Tags: linux, bash, sed

As a part of optimisation, I am trying to replace all Java files containing the string:

```
logger.trace("some trace message");
```

With:

```
if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
{
  logger.trace("some trace message");
}
```

N.B. Some trace message is not the exact string but an example. This string will be different for every instance.

I am using a bash script and sed but can't quite get the command right.

I have tried this in a bash script to insert before:

```
traceStmt="if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
{
  "
find . -type f -name '*.java' | xargs sed "s?\(logger\.trace\)\(.*\)?\1${traceStmt}?g"
```

I have also tried different variants but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using GNU `sed`:

```
$ cat file1.java
1
2
logger.trace("some trace message");
4
5

$ find . -type f -name '*.java' | xargs sed 's?\(logger\.trace\)\(.*\)?if (logger.isTraceEnabled())\n{\n    \1\2\n}?'
1
2
if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
{
    logger.trace("some trace message");
}
4
5
$
```

Comment: The console output shows the change but the file doesn't change.

Comment: @karen.  Use the `-i` option for `sed` to do in-situ replacement, i.e. `find . -type f -name '*.java' | xargs sed -i  's?\(logger\.trace\)\(.*\)?if (logger.isTraceEnabled())\n{\n    \1\2\n}?'

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to prevent adding new line endings

> `sed` will add `\n` to the end of files that do not end in `\n`)

You could try like:

```
perl -pi -e 's/logger.trace\("some trace message"\);/`cat input`/e' file.java
```

notice the ending `/e`

> The evaluation modifier `s///e` wraps an `eval{...}` around the replacement string and the evaluated result is substituted for the matched substring. Some examples:

In this case from your example, the file `input` contains:

```
if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
{
  logger.trace("some trace message");
}
```

If have multiple files you could try:

```
find . -type f -name '*.java' -exec perl -pi -e 's/logger.trace\("some trace message"\);/`cat input`/e' {} +
```